# Azure Cognitive Search: Cannot serach for text that starts with a specific term

Tags: azure, wildcard, azure-cognitive-search

I'm having a problem with Azure Cognitive Search. I have a "name" field in my search index, and I want to find text that only starts with the search term, not just any occurrence within the text. I've tried using both the default analyzer and the Keyword Analyzer, but I can't seem to get the results I want.

Let me give you an example of my data:

city red
red 1
red2

In this case, I only want to get "red 1" and "red2" as the results. But the search queries I've tried so far haven't worked out.

When I use the default analyzer, it returns everything,. On the other hand, with the Keyword Analyzer, I get no results at all.

Here are the search terms I've used:

"Re*"

Regular expression: "/Re*./i"

Unfortunately, neither of these approaches has given me the desired results. I thought using a regular expression with the Keyword Analyzer would do the trick, but it didn't work out.

Can someone please help me figure out what I might be doing wrong? Is there another way or a different search query syntax I should be using to get the results I need?

I'd really appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Request options:

SearchQueryType.Full,

SearchMode = SearchMode.Any (I have tried All as well)

Comment: Can you share the full request and documents you have tried? Specifying the wildcard operator should work (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-simple-syntax#prefix-search). Alternatively, you can use EdgeNGram tokenizer for better performance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-partial-matching#tune-query-performance

Comment: @giulianob yeah i do not know why the wildcard did not work. I don't what you mean by document. If you refering to source document, it is not the problem.  I have added the request options in the post above.

Answer (score 1):

As linked by @giulianob you will need to use a EdgeNGramTokenFilter along side the keyword_v2 tokenizer to get the starts with result.

Ref link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-partial-matching#tune-query-performance

EDIT: Actually this does not work when there is a space inbetween the search phrase.

```json
{
"fields": [
  {
  "name": "accountNumber",
  "analyzer":"myCustomAnalyzer",
  "type": "Edm.String",
  "searchable": true,
  "filterable": true,
  "retrievable": true,
  "sortable": false,
  "facetable": false
  }
],

"analyzers": [
  {
  "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
  "name":"myCustomAnalyzer",
  "charFilters":[],
  "tokenizer":"keyword_v2",
  "tokenFilters":["lowercase", "my_edgeNGram"]
  }
],
"tokenizers":[],
"charFilters": [],
"tokenFilters": [
  {
  "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2",
  "name":"my_edgeNGram",
  "minGram": 2,
  "maxGram": 25,
  "side": "front"
  }
]
}
```